# How do I disable LinkButton in gridview based on a value from another column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a status column which includes approved, rejected or cancelled. I have another Actions column which contain link buttons approve and reject. Now if the status is Cancelled, I want the link button to be disabled for that row.

I tried to use GridView1_DataBound event but couldn't figure out the logic.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {


                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    if (Server.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Trim()).Equals("Cancelled"))
                    {

                        //OR you can disable it instead of complately hiding it
                        ((LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: so you're saying the code above didn't work, is that correct? What debugging have you done to try and determine where it starts to go wrong?

Comment: P.S. in one place you use `e.Row.Cells` to identify the row, and in another you (seemingly randomly) use the much longer `GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells` to do the same job. Why make it more complicated? Make your code consistent and shorter and nicer to read by doing it the easy way.

Comment: What kinda object is being used in the GridView?  Like, if my GridView.DataSource = Collection(Of Products), then on RowDataBound I'm dealing with 1 individual product.  So I'd then cast that row to be the product object, and I could easily access the products property to see if it has been canceled.

Comment: @JohnPete22 good idea. But I assume you meant you would cast the [DataItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem?view=netframework-4.8) of the row rather than the row itself? :-)

Comment: @ADyson Yes that is correct.  Sorry, sometimes I forget I need to be extra specific.  Example would be ````Product item = (Product)e.Row.DataItem````

Comment: My Status column is in Boundfield. I'm just updating Status in database once approve or reject link is clicked and displaying it on GridView. My Actions column is a template field which has these linkbuttons.

Comment: Sounds like you need a CommandName then:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandname?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: In short, add CommandNames to the LinkButtons that you want to catch, and then add a GridView_RowCommand function that you'll link up to your GridView.  And if that ````e.CommandName = "theCommandYoureLookingFor"```` then implement whatever logic you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method A**

The following should work:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Enabled='<%# !(Eval("Status").ToString().Equals("Cancelled")) %>'>Approve</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Enabled='<%# !(Eval("Status").ToString().Equals("Cancelled")) %>'>Reject</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Method B**

Nevertheless, if you do insist on the code-behind approach the safest way to access the `LinkButton` controls is the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ApproveButton" runat="server">Approve</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="RejectButton" runat="server">Reject</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Equals("Cancelled"))
        {
            ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("ApproveButton")).Enabled = false;
            ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("RejectButton")).Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

Your code doesn't work because the `LinkButton` controls are not placed in the cell's `Controls` collection in the way you're expecting them to. Find out yourself by placing a breakpoint inside the inner condition of `GridView1_RowDataBound` and check out the items of the `Controls` collection. You'd be surprised!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gridView_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Column1" DataField="Column1" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Column2" DataField="Column2" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text='<%#Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAction" runat="server">Approve</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void gridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var status = (e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus") as Label).Text;
        if (status == "Cancelled")
        {
            (e.Row.FindControl("lnkAction") as LinkButton).DisableControl("Disabled button.");
        }
    }
}
```

And to disable the button you can use an extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
      public static TControl DisableControl<TControl>(this TControl control, string desableMessage) where TControl : WebControl
    {
        control.Attributes.Add("disabled", "");
        control.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "tooltip");
        control.Attributes.Add("title", disableMessage);
        control.Enabled = false;
        return control;
    }
}
```